# How to get the currently time only

Tags: java, datetime

Wha would be the equivalent in Java for this C# code:

```
DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay //This
DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") //Or This
```

I'm finding a lot of things, some of them may be deprecated because it has 2 years or more, others are really complex for such a simple thing, and I'm sure there is a simpler way to do so.

I tried:

```
import java.util.Date;

Date d = new Date();
System.out.println(d);   //Result:  Wed Oct 28 00:46:29 2015  

If I try:  

System.out.println(d.getTime()); //Result:  1446000426285
```

I need to get only time: `H:mm:ss`

Comment: `Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString()`  will get you `dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyy` which you can then just parse?

Answer (score 3):

You can use SimpleDateFormat in java. date.getTime() gives you the milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

```
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: Getting some erros: Can't find class `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro You need to import the class, `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;` before you can use it

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, in Java, date/time objects are just a container for the amount of time which has passed since a given point in time (like the Unix epoch), so they tend not to have there own concept of formatting.

Formatting is normally managed by a supporting API, like `java.text.DateFormat` or `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`

If you're using Java 8, you could start with `LocalTime`

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME.format(time));
```

which prints `13:51:13.466`.

If you need a specific format, you can supply your own pattern to `DateTimeFormatter`, something like `System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm:ss a").format(time));` which prints `1:52:31 PM`

Have a look at [Date and Time Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html) for more details